# In FontBook, how do I re-enable the "...Remove Font Family?" warning?

Tags: font-book

As it turns out, the pop-up warning before removing a font family in FontBook is quite handy for accidental clicks. After choosing to not show the warning message previously, how do I re-enable this function? There seems to be nothing in FontBook prefences that addresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in **macOS Catalina**, with **Font Book** closed, from **Terminal**:

```
defaults delete com.apple.FontBook FBRemoveFontsFromLibrary
```

Allows this *dialog box* to show again:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @user3439894. This was most helpful.